# Windows - Use a program as a virtual printer?

Tags: c#, windows, printing, registry, printers

I'm looking for a simple installer, or even a registry file, that can create a virtual printer that just redirect the file about to be printed to my program

Today I use Printer++ that use `DLLs` but it's not really practical for companies..

Today the program is installed in the `ProgramFiles` directory, all I need is the `Virtual Printer` that will redirect the file to my program
 (as command line parameters)

any ideas ?

Comment: "I'm looking for <software X>" is off-topic on this site. Also, I don't see any relation with C# or the registry. On an unrelated note, in the Windows architecture printing is not tied to files. A Point-of-Sales application may very well print receipt forms from a database. The closest relation is that a file _extension_ may have a "print" verb, which essentially means there's a program installed which knows how to print that file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, if yes, could you share how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/). It is an open-source windows printer port that simply redirects all printer output to a specific program or script.